# Angular-ui-router doesn't have a default state and can't transition from it

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I having some problems with the the angular-ui-router. When I click on a ui-sref I get the message

```
"Error: Could not resolve 'X' from state ''
transitionTo@http:/
```

Where `X` is the state in **site-header** that I'm trying to go to.

I think this means that there isn't a default state, but I'm not sure. In any case here are what I think are the relevant file parts:

**index.html**

```
<div class="container" ng-cloak>
    <a ui-sref="home"></a>
    <div ui-view></div>
</div>
```

**app.config.js**

```
angular.module('fTA')
    .config(function($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider) {
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

        $stateProvider.state('home', {
            url: '/',
            template: '<p>This is home view</p>'
        });

        $stateProvider.state('login' {
            url: '/login',
            templateUrl: '/views/login.html',
            controller: 'LoginCtrl'
        });
    });
```

Where /views/login.html are the path names of the files in my directory.

My understanding is that since `urlRouterProvider` is '/' then I should see `<p>This is home view</p>` in at '/'. But I don't. So, what retarded thing have I done so that even hard coded templates don't show up.

Comment: have you tried to rename the state from '/' into 'home'?

Comment: @RadimKöhler Yes, its the same. X is just home in that case.

Comment: if the state name is 'home' then `ui-sref="home" should work. I would anyhow suggest to use home rather than '/' in the state name. Also, (really not sure here) but won't your `ng-include=""` replace the content of the div and remove  `<div ui-view></div>`

Comment: @RadimKöhler I don't think it will. But I just tested it without the ng-include and only a <a ui-sref="home">Home</a> before the <div ui-view></div> and I get the same message.

Answer (score 1):

I just [created a plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/eq62TLBQHHfbqICa1Rd6?p=preview) - and change only one thing: added comma after 'login'

```
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

    $stateProvider.state('home', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'tpl.html'
    });

 // $stateProvider.state('login' {
    $stateProvider.state('login', {
        url: '/login',
        templateUrl: 'tpl.html',
        controller: 'LoginCtrl'
    });
```

And this is working now:

```
  <a ui-sref="home">home</a>
  <a ui-sref="login">login</a>
```

The working plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/eq62TLBQHHfbqICa1Rd6?p=preview)

Comment: I think one thing that seems different is the templateUrl. In your plunker you have a ng-template. What is the templateUrl relative too? Index.html?

Comment: That is good spot.. I would say for sure try: templateUrl: 'views/login.html', without leading slash

Comment: Thanks for your help. The problem ended up being that I wasn't including app.config.js in index.html. I knew it was something stupid. Thanks for your help.